# "Unable to locate mail spool file." when using Thunderbird and Gmail

Tags: thunderbird

I am using ubuntu 13.04 and I set my gmail account as default outgoing server.
when I press get mail in thunderbird I get the message

> "Unable to locate mail spool file".

any suggestions. also how do I get the terminal?

Comment: You have other mail programs downloaded and installed?

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the file browser and type CTRL+H to see the hidden files and then delete the .thunderbird folder. Thunderbird should open right this time, but you need to configure your aaccount again. Hope it help you